# How to make `attributedReadMoreText` in `ReadMoreTextView` library not selectable - swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview, iosdeployment

I am a new iOS programming. Now i am creating a sample app which display text using `ReadMoreTextView` library. My content may contain many lines but by using this library i can `maximumNumberOfLines` to display how many lines of content should be displayed. I implement those content in `cell` of `UITableView` and i have problem is that, when i use `label.attributedReadMoreText = NSAttributedString(string: "...")` then end of content will display `...` and when i click on it and then whole content will be display so, my question is that: How to not letting user click on that `...` because i want user to click on `cell` then i will show another view and display whole content there?

How can i achieve something like this? Thank in advance.

This is how i set `UITextView`

```
lazy var categoryShortDetailLabel: ReadMoreTextView = {

    let label = ReadMoreTextView()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFCompactText-Regular", size: 16)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.isEditable = false
    label.isSelectable = false
    label.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
    label.shouldTrim = true
    label.attributedReadMoreText = NSAttributedString(string: "...")

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label

}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView/blob/master/Sources/ReadMoreTextView.swift), I found that, the **ReadMoreTextView** is meant to provide you the feature like, **ReadMore** and **ReadLess** for the larger texts in textView.

However your requirement is to stop that functionality. Now, if you take a look at the [code here](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView/blob/master/Sources/ReadMoreTextView.swift), you will get the idea, that the function **shoreMoreText** and it's a **private function** so, can't override it. and this function is expanding the texts and setting the numberOfLines to zero. so, what you can do is, comment the code within and return from function to stop doing the action. Also as the ReadMoreTextView is Licensed as MIT([Read licence here](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView/blob/master/LICENSE)) so, it's okay to modify the code.

```
private func showMoreText() {
    return
    /*if let readLessText = readLessText, text.hasSuffix(readLessText) { return }
    
    shouldTrim = false
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0

    if let originalAttributedText = _originalAttributedText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString {
        attributedText = _originalAttributedText
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
        if let attributedReadLessText = attributedReadLessText {
            originalAttributedText.append(attributedReadLessText)
        }
        textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: originalAttributedText)
    }
    
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    invokeOnSizeChangeIfNeeded()*/
}
```

Try and share your results.

Hope it helps!